# QT Debugging QFile::remove() Windows 10 MSVS 2019

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, uac, qfile

I am working on a QT application that has to communicate with a few Windows-utilities.
The result of these utilities are a couple of “production-files” that should be listed in a “filenames-txt-file” for further use.
The production of such a “filenames-txt-file” with the list of “production-files” is done with QT using QFileInfo.
Sometimes an old “filenames-txt-file” already exists in the working-directory and should be removed before it can be created with the new results.

Here is the problem: 
QFile::remove("somefile") does not work while debugging.
 It works fine, when I run the Exe in the debug-folder outside MSVS, 
 and it works fine running the release version.

While debugging, I get this messages:

```
if (QFile::exists(filenameFull)) {
    QFile f (filenameFull);     
    qDebug() << f.remove(filenameFull);     // returns false
    qDebug() << f.errorString();            // returns “unknown error”
}
```

I elevated Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 to run as administrator.
I did set the UAC execution level to “highestAvailable”.
Is anything else needed to make this code working while debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @hyde.
The issue was indeed that `filenameFull` was opened all the time. 
 Not in the code itself, but in the `Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments` 
 It was hanging there from an earlier stage in the  coding process.
It explains as well why running the EXE outside the debugging-process was running fine.
Lesson: keep my coding steps clear at all times....
Thanks for getting me back on track.

Answer (score 0):

It may be unrelated but instead `f.remove(filenameFull)` you can just use `f.remove()` or `QFile::remove(filenameFull)`.

`QFile::remove` on windows uses winapi function `DeleteFileW(("\\\\?\\" + QDir::toNativeSeparators(filenameFull)).utf16())` where "\\?\" is used to avoid MAX_PATH limitation. Try calling this function directly and analyze result.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling static function, `QFile::remove(QString filename)`, so `f` does not see the error. So try this:

```
if (QFile::exists(filenameFull)) {
    QFile f (filenameFull);
    qDebug() << f.exists();
    qDebug() << f.remove();      
    qDebug() << f.errorString();
}
```

That should solve the part about not getting error string.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement of the code. Now I get the errorString "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." If I check this in Explorer it is referring to the EXE I am debugging. So my question could be more specific: Why is MSVS occupying a file while I am asking it to remove? The file is removed outside the debugger, running the EXE. So the code seems ok.

Comment: @cvz So just to be clear, which process has `filenameFull` file open, do you know? Anyway, which ever it is, on Windows only way around is to make sure the file is not open. Do you have it open in MSVS editor?

Comment: Explorer says that the 'filenameFull' is owned by the executable that I am working with in MSVS (debugging) . As far as I know 'filenameFull' is not opened at an earlier stage by that executable. The same executable, run outside MSVS, does remove 'filenameFull' without complaining about being open. So far now, I only see a difference in behavior in/outside MSVS. I just would like to save a QStringList to disk with the name 'filenameFull'. A workaround would be truncate 'filenameFull' - if it exists - and than write it.

Comment: One possibility is, that the application is being executed multiple times, that is the process of the previous run has not exited. Check the PIDs to be sure.

Comment: With Process Explorer I can see only one version of my exe that is owned by `msvsmon.exe`. So only one PID.